# mysql_insert_id() always returns 0

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I'm trying to retrieve the last id number inserted with mysql_insert_id() but always return 0, my id field is auto increment so I don't know why it returns 0 thanks. please help

```
include 'C:\xampp\htdocs\Student_evaluation\functions.php';

if(!loggedin())
{
header("Location: http://localhost/dev/userarea.php");
exit();
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
//get data
$name = $_POST['name'];
$f_lastname = $_POST['f_lastname'];
$second_lastname = $_POST['second_lastname'];
$student_number = $_POST['student_number'];
$semester_year = $_POST['semester_year'];
$course = $_POST['course'];
$section = $_POST['section'];
$grade = $_POST['grade'];
$student_perform = $_POST['student_perform'];
$comment_box = $_POST['comment_box'];


$sql = "INSERT INTO `students`(`name`, `first_lastname`, `second_lastname`, `numero_estudiante`, `semester`, `course`, `section`, `f_grade`, `students_perform`, `comments`) 
VALUES ('$name','$f_lastname','$second_lastname','$student_number','$semester_year','$course','$section','$grade','$student_perform','$comment_box')";



$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","rememberme");
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

echo "ID of last inserted record is: " . mysql_insert_id();

}
```

Comment: `mysql` or `mysqli`, decide what you want first.

Comment: you're mixing up mysqli and mysql functions.

Comment: are you confused or is that a typo?  your are using `mysql_insert_id();` not `mysqli_insert_id();`

Comment: Go with mysqli. mysql functions are deprecated

Comment: That SQL injection...

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Constructing a string in PHP does not magically perform a database query. The call to `mysqli_query` performs a database query.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Nobody has "put the wagon before the horse" and I don't know why you keep saying he has.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit My mistake. I didn't know that the DB connection could be placed like that, after the query. Comments deleted.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: It's not. As I said already, the connection takes place before the query is run. The line which begins `$sql =` creates a PHP string; nothing more. The query is executed by the call to `mysqli_query`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit OP has `$sql = "INSERT INTO....` then `$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","rememberme");` in posted code above. I'm not imagining this.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: I already said, several times, `$sql =` _does not execute a query_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using one library (*mysqli*) to perform the query, then another (*mysql*) to obtain the auto-increment ID. That can't work. Among other issues, you haven't even connected to the database with the second library!

Consistently use [*mysqli*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) or, better yet, PDO, which will help you plug your blinding security flaw.

Comment: Now its working thanks, I guess I wasn't paying attention t that detail.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this (using `mysqli_insert_id`):

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","rememberme");
$sql = "INSERT INTO ...";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
echo "ID of last inserted record is: " . mysqli_insert_id($con);
```

[mysql_insert_id](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) and [mysqli_insert_id](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) are both different and you are using `mysqli` so use `mysqli_insert_id` instead of `mysql_insert_id` and it's better to use [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead of [mysql](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php).